# Error in sourceCpp after installing Rtools

Tags: r, rcpp

A month ago I installed Rtools all by default options on my personal computer and was able to write C++ functions in R ever since. Now I am trying to install Rtools on my company's computer and unable to correctly install Rtools. I believe it has something to do with the PATH or some relevant thing that I don't quite understand. Help is so needed. Below are my steps and results:

1. Install R-3.03 in the local drive c; successful
2. `install.packages(c("Rcpp","installr"));` successful
3. `library(installr)`
4. `install.Rtools()`. In this step there's one thing suspicious:

[image]

I only chose "Save version information to registry".
5. library(Rcpp); evalCpp("1 + 1"); and I got the following:
running command:

```
make -f "C:/R-    30~1.3/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/R-30~1.3/share/make/winshlib.mk"   SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)
```

Warning message:

```
SHLIB="sourceCpp_35432.dll" OBJECTS="file1bb831d14d68.o"' had status 127  
    Error in sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild,     showOutput = showOutput,  : 
    Error 1 occurred building shared library.
    WARNING: The tools required to build C++ code for R were not found.
    Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools:
    http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools
```

And I did restart the computer to see if miracles can happen, but no.
Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: You should have checked the other box as well.  Your problem is that Rtools isn't on the PATH.  I don't believe there is any harm in reinstalling Rtools but make sure you check the box to modify the path.

Comment: Have you carefully checked your Windows PATH variable. As emphasized in [this section of the R-admin manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#The-Windows-toolset), "It is important to set your PATH properly".

Comment: And please sort this out with the author of `installr` (Hi Tal!) which is not a tool we support.  All you need is described in our docs and the R manuals.