# R error message when calling libraries and installing packages

Tags: r, plyr

I started to get some error message in R when calling libraries that usually work very well. I decided to re-install the packages that were concerned, and also ran into some error..

Any idea what's going on? I'm about to throw my computer thru the window..

```
   > library( "DESeq2" )
    Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
      there is no package called ‘plyr’
    Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘DESeq2’

   > install.packages("plyr_1.8.2.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
    Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Sun/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
    (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
    * installing *source* package 'plyr' ...
    ** package 'plyr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    ** libs

    *** arch - i386
    Warning: running command 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.0/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.0/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="plyr.dll" OBJECTS="RcppExports.o loop-apply.o split-numeric.o"' had status 127
    ERROR: compilation failed for package 'plyr'
    * removing 'C:/Users/Sun/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/plyr'
    Warning messages:
    1: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Sun\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" "plyr_1.8.2.tar.gz"' had status 1 
    2: In install.packages("plyr_1.8.2.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source") :
      installation of package ‘plyr_1.8.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Have you installed all the software necessary to compile packages from source? Why aren't you just installing binaries from CRAN?

Comment: take a look here - seems like somewhat similar error - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798234/error-in-sourcecpp-after-installing-rtools

Comment: @RInatM Thank you but that doesn't resolve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Joran, installing from CRAN actually solved the issue.

```
install.packages("plyr")
```